# How can I change OSX's spinning beachball pointer animation?

Tags: customization, macos

I want to change the **spinning beachball** pointer animation used in OSX to indicate an application is not responding to system events, to something else, like a funny GIF, or maybe just a different icon. Is anyone familiar enough with the operating system to know where files for that animation are stored? Is it a script? Is it just a GIF? Is it even possible to change it?

Here's the image I mean:

[image]

Comment: Currently, there is no way to change it.

Comment: What is the rainbow loading animation ?

Comment: @user1598390 check the question ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you go to `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors` you'll might find something useful :

```
MBP-Thomas in ~
○ → cd /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors

 MBP-Thomas in /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/HIServices.framework/Versions/A/Resources/cursors
○ → ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  41 root  wheel   1,4K 13 sep  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x  39 root  wheel   1,3K 26 mai 23:30 ..
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 busybutclickable
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 cell
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 closedhand
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 contextualmenu
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 copy
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 countingdownhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 countingupandownhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 countinguphand
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 cross
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 help
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 ibeamvertical
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 makealias
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 move
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 notallowed
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 openhand
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 pointinghand
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 poof
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizedown
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeeast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeeastwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeleft
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeleftright
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenorth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenortheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenortheastsouthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenorthsouth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenorthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizenorthwestsoutheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeright
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizesouth
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizesoutheast
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizesouthwest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeup
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizeupdown
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 resizewest
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   170B  9 déc  2013 screenshotselection
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 screenshotwindow
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 zoomin
drwxr-xr-x   4 root  wheel   136B  9 déc  2013 zoomout
```

Which are a lot of folder containing cursor pictures

Comment: How do people find stuff like this lol

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX kind of simple : `sudo find / -iname "*cursor*"`

Comment: Oh, I never realized that searches within bundles like `.framework`

Comment: This is indeed where most *pointers* are located, but none of these folders contain the beach ball we are looking for...