# Where can I find El Capitan's default and beachball/busy cursors?

Tags: macos

I saw from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/134892/77119) how I can get *most* of the cursors, but the busy and default cursors aren't there. Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

The default cursor is available here:

> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EFILogin.framework/Versions/A/Resources/EFIResourceBuilder.bundle/Contents/Resources/loginui_cursor@2x.png

I can't seem to find the busy cursor, but I did find an older-seeming version of it here:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLUT.framework/Versions/A/Resources/waitCursor.tiff

Comment: Oh nice! I remember finding the default cursor on Yosemite. Interesting that the beachball is so hard to find.