# What is the angular velocity of the macOS beach ball?

Tags: macos, animation

Does anyone know the exact angular velocity of the spinning beach ball animation from El Capitan onwards? I'm trying to create an animation of it from scratch and googling has come up with nothing.

Comment: While not a duplicate of your question, [this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238519/88313) can tell you where the graphic file is located.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The animation is 15 frames long with a delay of 0.033 seconds between frames.

[image]

Comment: I have to assume that 0.033 is actually 0.0333… (i.e. 30fps on a 60Hz monitor), so it would actually be exactly 0.5 seconds long. Also are you sure it completes a full revolution in the animation? 2 rotations per second seems far too fast.

Comment: @Dave The plist says 0.033000000000000002.

Comment: The reason I added a .png is because this is what I'm seeing in Safari. http://imgur.com/EzpPlUR Or I should say what I'm not seeing, as the .svg is not legible even if I zoom in all the way. You should add the .svg as a .png or .jpg to the answer, not a link to your own server.

Comment: From the image shown here: http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/124915/200721 I believe that the animation is actually only through 1/5 of the circle (since there are 5 spokes), so divide your answer by 5 to get the true value (1 rotation every 2.5 seconds).

Comment: @Dave I was asking about the updated beach ball cursor (from El Capitan onwards). The old one is much slower. 0.5 seconds per rotation seems right for the newer one.